React DND - Can't drop draggable items in conditionally rendered droppable
I'm using react DND hello-pangea which is a library from beautiful-react-dnd, but unfortunately, I can't drop items in a conditionally rendered droppable.
I've tried to render the component conditionally and show the droppable using the css display property, but I faced the same problem and nothing works.
I want to hide empty droppables and show them only when I'm dragging items.
I've forked this code from hello-pangea documentation example and added a conditionally display none to the droppable element and the same bug appears. My example is in this Sandbox link. The main example from react-beautiful-dnd there
Thanks all 
